# What causes these light leaks on bulk loaded film

Tags: film, light-leaks, bulk-load

I have several rolls with similar light leaks such as below, but more examples [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB0bc.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pVPH.png).

These rolls are all bulk loaded, in recycled canisters (meaning rolls that came from a lab which new film was spooled into). The leaks appear in various cameras that have not shown issues with other, non bulk loaded rolls. Additionally, the leak is always in the same spot on the frame. This last point is not limited to full frame, as the last linked example comes from a Hasselblad X-Pan.

The facts:

1. The leak is most likely occurring in-camera due to the consistent spacing with different frame sizes
2. There appears no gradation in the intensity of the leak across the roll
3. The leak does not move across the roll
4. There is a distinct S-shape recurring in all instances

Any idea what could cause these artefacts? I am puzzled, as I would think a canister with shot up light seals would be leaking light outside of a camera just as much.

[image]

Comment: Further, a cassette with bad velvet wouldn't leak *inside* the camera -- it's dark in there.  You've got a puzzler here.

Comment: @ZeissIkon it's only dark to a certain extent. Some cameras have windows, and I wonder if this issue is specific to that. And of course there's a certain burst of light that happens with photography ;)

Comment: Bad light seals on a film reminder window would leak on commercial rolls, not just reloads, and the intentional exposure wouldn't overwhelm other exposures on the film.

Comment: Can you try loading some rolls in cassettes made for bulk loading, instead of reused commercial ones?  Looking at these, I wonder if it isn't chemical fogging from something in the velvets on the cassettes you're getting from the lab.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm not suggesting the window's seals are bad (which I confirm are in great shape). At this point all my logical options are exhausted, so I am looking at _anything_. These windows are a source of light, so a possible though unlikely source of leaks

Comment: @ZeissIkon I could, though testing is unfortunately made difficult by how haphazard this leak is. I have done multiple tests where I rolled some frames into reused canisters and developed them immediately without loading/exposing, without any artefacts. With chemical fogging, would the effect not decrease over the course of the roll?

Comment: I have just checked, and the position of the leak does not correspond with the position of the film in the felt as the next frame is in front of the film gate

Comment: How were the rolls processed? Did you develop them yourself or send them out?

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens these are rolls from different people. I don't know how they had the rolls developed individually

Comment: Just so I understand, are you saying  these are not your cameras?

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens That's right. We're now wondering if the coated labels are light piping into the camera from the film window

Comment: Just to better understand, have any of the cameras been inspected for light seal quality  and/or verified to be non-problematic with other films?

Comment: Yes. I've tested the issue myself now, so I have first hand experience. The leak instantly disappears once the film confirmation window is covered up. The light seals are in immaculate shape. You can see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of sleuthing, it was discovered the light leaks are caused by the transparent coating on the bulk loaded labels.

These leaks were only present in cameras with a film confirmation window. Regardless of the condition of the seals around this windows, leaks would show in almost every frame. Covering this window would instantly prevent these leaks from showing. It is thought that the coating facilitates light piping, circumventing the light seals around the confirmation window.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, thank you for your help

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, thank you for your help

Comment: Great job sleuthing out the issue! Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: That's one I haven't seen before.  Seems like plain paper gum-back labels (or just tape with hand written data) would be superior (or use cameras that don't have built-in light leak windows).

Comment: @ZeissIkon true. I am looking into having my supplier switch to a matte coating or no coating at all. Writing hundreds of labels each month is a little bit too laborious

Answer (score 0):

Same place on every frame suggests the take up spool side of the camera to me.

The consistency of light leak intensity and complete exposure are also consistent with that edge of the camera. It doesn’t look like an exposure artifact.

The s-shape suggests a bowing in the film in the sprocket hole to sprocket hole direction.

A possible cause via bulk loading would be how the bulk film is attached to the spindle or old leader. My experience is the amount and orientation of the tape is important to smooth operation of bulk rolled cartridges.

[edit] worth noting the Xpan spools all the film out of the cartridge and then “rewinds” each frame into the cartridge when exposed. This behavior means that a problem with the hinge seals would leak light onto the film before exposing a frame rather than afterwards. This has implications for troubleshooting procedures.

[edit] I googled "Xpan light leak." This [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnalogCommunity/comments/nhj3y5/anybody_have_experience_fixing_light_seals_in_an/) looks like a light leak in the same location on an Xpan. This [Flickr post](https://www.flickr.com/groups/hasselblad/discuss/72157631001804892/72157687082339025) about an Xpan light leak also looks similar. These [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTkWC.jpg) linked from this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnalogCommunity/comments/rzh01k/negative_issuexpan_white_lines_on_several_frames/) have a similar Xpan light leak.

Comment: Problematically with this explanation is that the leaks show up on different cameras with different frame sizes that show no issues on other films. Additionally to that, there is a definite lack of leak intensity, with sometimes the leak barely being present at all. However, especially considering different frame widths have the leak show up in the same place seems to indicate the space between canister and film gate to me

Comment: To reply to your comment about taping the film to the canister: using scotch tape I attach new film to the leftover film still sticking out the canister along the width of the film. As far as I can tell, and I've shot rolls myself, everything runs smoothly

Comment: @timvrhn intensity of a hinge side light leak will very with the amount of time ‘the next frame’ sits next to the hinge and the intensity of the light. If it is shot a few seconds after the previous frame in indoor light, the light leak may not be visible. If the next frame sits twenty minutes on a tripod in full sun it can be baked in fully.

Comment: @timvrhn My understanding is the Xpan can shoot both panoramic and 3:2. But what are the other cameras?

Comment: @timvrhn scotch tape traveling through the canister felt has created issues for me, though I use reloadable canisters. Now I use gaffers tape and not so much it passes through the felt.

Comment: I agree that such a leaky hinge could cause this issue. However, considering this happens with a multitude of cameras and _only_ with the bulk loaded rolls, I believe this is not the cause. Other cameras were for example the Contax G2 and the Nikon F4

Comment: What kind of issues did you experience? For me, the transportation of the film through the felt is smooth and the tape picks up none of the felt

Answer (score -1):

Bulk loading film as its share of perils.  Bulk film comes to you in a light-proof wrapper packed in a light-proof metal or plastic canister. Today’s films are likely panchromatic (sensitive to all colors) thus no safelight can be uses (exception – a dim green far distant might be OK). Best if no safelight is used.

You must unpack and unspool the film in total darkness. A darkroom that is totally dark is hard to find. You may think its safe but after being in total darkness for about 20 minutes you might change your mind. The human eye will dark-adapt over time and you might discover that some of the dark has escaped.

Assuming your work area is safe, now you go to work. You strip off a meter or so and spool this into a cassette. Is the cassette light-tight? Many a roll has spoiled due to risky cassettes. Also, the base of the film can allow light piping. That’s light entering the cassette via the clear film base. 35mm film often has a gray base to fort light piping. Some have an opaque backing called a remjet (removable jet black). This is lampblack carbon coated using an adhesive that softens in an alkaline developer.

Often work using a bulk loader. This is a light proof spooler that we load in total darkness. Sometimes the bulk loader allows the dark to leak out.
I could go on and on about the different dangers but likely you have experienced some of these threats.

Comment: I've bulk loaded close to 4000 rolls, the majority of which indeed with a rEmjet layer. Very interesting stuff, and definitely noticed the many steps at which light can be introduced. An interesting one is static discharges, occurring frequently on/in the black light bags the bulk rolls come in. Frustrating!

Comment: This talks around the already accepted self-answer.